# how to stop a for loop after number of iteration

Tags: c++

I'm trying to stop the for loop ( `for (int j = 0; j< num; j++` ) after three times. If I put an `if` statement `if (num ==3)` to force the loop to stop, it works ten times.

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double store[3];
    int num=1;
    int i=0;
    while(i<10)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j< num; j++)
        {
            cout << " " << store[j] << "\n";
        }
        num++;

        if (num == 3)
        {
            num = 0;
        }

        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: @akaBase The value of `num` is never greater than 2 when the `for` loop is started!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow Farhan! If you need to stop the `for` loop after 3 times, you can use [break](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/break).

```cpp
for (int j = 0; j< num; j++)
{
    if (j == 3) break;
    cout << " " << store[j] << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop is never running more than **twice** in each iteration of the outer `while` loop. Moreover, on many of those outer loops, it doesn't run at all (because `num == 0`).

If you put some 'test' values into `store`, you will see what is actually happening:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double store[3];
    int num = 1;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 10)
    {
        store[0] = store[1] = store[2] = i; /// Add some test values (shows the i count)
        for (int j = 0; j < num; j++)
        {
            cout << " " << store[j] << "\n";
        }
        num++;

        if (num == 3)
        {
            num = 0;
        }

        i++;
    }
}
```

What you are seeing is the ***total*** number of runs through the `for` loop added up over each `while` loop - and this just happens to be 10.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate `num`, or at most `3`, times, then just say so in your loop:

```
for (int j = 0; j < std::max(num, 3); ++j)
```

Comment: See my comment in the question!